# Adding a service provider using connected app

Tags: single-sign-on, connected-apps, identity, service

i am following the tutorial http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Implementing_Single_Sign-On_Across_Multiple_Organizations in step 6 when i try to add Service privider in Identity provider .there is no new button  and instead an info "Service Providers are now created via Connected Apps. Click here." .so i click on this message and redirected to create Connected App page.i fill up the Connnected app name ,Api Name automatically assigned in web app settings i checked enable SAML.
then filed the fields as described in this.but 7th step is

> ```
> Assign this SSO configuration to any Profiles of your choosing
> ```

now when i go back to Identity Provider page .i am not able to see any service provider ?? so how to assign SSo configuration to any profile please guideline !!

Comment: You can add Profiles to Connected Apps , via a related list. Have a look on the Connected App.

Comment: @techtrekker: how to add profiles to the connected apps? I cant see anything like related list. ALSO I am having my SP in my local machine . still can I use sales force?

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce changed the way adding a service provider worked with the Winter 14 release and made it substantially more complicated.  Here is documentation that I found that describes the process:  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=identity_provider_examples.htm&language=en